# Setting Custom-Secret-ID using Powershell or curl not working

Tags: hashicorp-vault

In the following Powershell code, I'm trying to set a custom-secret-id on an approle.

```
Function GetNewSecretId {
    Param(
        [Parameter()] [String[]]$approle
    )
    try
    {
        $uri = "$($env:VAULT_ADDR)" + "/v1/auth/approle/role/$($approle)/custom-secret-id"
        $header = @{
            "X-Vault-Token"="$($env:VAULT_TOKEN)"
            "X-Vault-Namespace"="$($env:VAULT_NAMESPACE)"
        }

        $GUID = [guid]::NewGuid()

        $payload = 
        @{
            "secret_id"="$($GUID)"
            "ttl"="8760h"
            } | ConvertTo-Json
        if($debug) 
        {
            Write-Host "Sending Custom Secret-ID"
            Write-Host($($uri))
            Write-Host($($header|ConvertTo-Json))
            Write-Host($($payload))
        }
        #***************************************************************
        # Call the method to get the passed secrets
        #***************************************************************
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -ContentType 'application/json' -Method POST -Uri $uri -Body $payload    
        #***************************************************************
        # this would be the result to send back from the function:
        $response.data.secret_id
        $env:SECRET_ID=$response.data.secret_id
        Write-Host($env:SECRET_ID)
    }
    catch [System.Net.WebException]
    {
        $msg = $_.Exception.Message + ": in GetNewSecretId: $($response)"
        $status = $_.Exception.Status
        $hr = "{0:x8}" -f ($_.Exception.HResult)
        $innerException = $_.Exception.InnerException
        $h = $header | ConvertTo-Json
        #Just issue a warning about being unable to send the notification...
        Write-Warning("`n`t[$status] `n`t[0x$hr] `n`t[$msg] `n`t[$innerException]`n`n[URI] $uri`n`t[Header] $h")
        return $False
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error with this defined policy on the approle that I'm logged into; it's not the same approle that is being passed into the command. It is an approle that has permissions to do anything on any other role.

```
# Grant 'create' & 'update' permission on the 'auth/approle/role/*/custom-secret-id' path
path "auth/approle/role/*/custom-secret-id" {
   capabilities = ["create", "delete", "update"]
}
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Actual error:

```
WARNING: 
    [ProtocolError] 
    [0x80131509] 
    [The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.: in GetNewSecretId: ] 
    []

[URI] https://myVaultUri/v1/auth/approle/role/<my approle>/custom-secret-id
    [Header] {
    "X-Vault-Namespace":  "<my namespace",
    "X-Vault-Token":  "<My Token after logging in>"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the error please?

Comment: @lxop, See edit above

Comment: I wonder if it is requiring some other permission - try adding all the other capabilities to the list, see if that works, if not try granting full permission to all paths and see if that works too. I'm not suggesting this as a fix, just a debugging step.

Comment: Just added sudo to the capabilities and tried doing it via CLI and still getting permission denied. Will be getting with our Vault admin on Thur

Comment: What about with `read` added to the capabilities, and with `"*"` for the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, changing the policy to this is what made it begin to work:

```
# Grant 'create' & 'update' permission on the 'auth/approle/role/*/custom-secret-id' path
path "auth/approle/role/+/custom-secret-id" {
   capabilities = ["create", "delete", "update"]
}
```